# Gradient is equal to 'None'

Tags: pytorch, backpropagation

I have two networks. The output of the first network is the input to the other. In order to calculate the loss for the second network, I use vanilla policy gradient. I want to backpropagate this loss into the first network. After checking if the gradeints has changed, I see that they are all none.
I first load the first network (a pre-trained autoencoer in my network this way):

```
def load_checkpoint(filepath, model):
   checkpoint = torch.load(filepath)
   model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
   for parameter in model.parameters():
       parameter.requires_grad = True


  model.train()
  return model
```

Then I define the optimizers for both networks this way:

```
class MultipleOptimizer(object):
    def __init__(self, *op):
        self.optimizers = op

    def zero_grad(self):
        for op in self.optimizers:
            op.zero_grad()

    def step(self):
        for op in self.optimizers:
            op.step()

opt = MultipleOptimizer(SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1, momentum=0.9), Adam(logits_net.parameters(), lr=lr))
```

the reward function is:

```
#Reward function
def reward(x, act):
    #print('action', act)
    #print('x  type', type(x))
    km = KMeans(act, n_init=20, n_jobs=4)
    y_pred = km.fit_predict(x.detach().cpu().numpy())# seems we can only get a centre from batch
    #print('k-means output type', type(y_pred))
    sil_score = sil(x.detach().cpu().numpy(), y_pred)
    #print('sil score', sil_score)
    
    return sil_score
```

The architecture of the second neural net and an alternative to avoid (logits=logits.mean(0)):

```
def mlp(sizes, activation=nn.Tanh, output_activation=nn.Identity):
# Build a feedforward neural network. outputs are the logits
    layers = []
    for j in range(len(sizes)-1):
        act = activation if j < len(sizes)-2 else output_activation
        layers += [nn.Linear(sizes[j], sizes[j+1]), act()]

    return nn.Sequential(*layers)



class mlp2(torch.nn.Module):
def __init__(self):

    super(mlp2, self).__init__()
    self.linear1 = nn.Linear(10,100)
    self.relu1 = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
    self.linear2 = torch.nn.Linear(100,100)
    self.linear3 = torch.nn.Linear(100,20)
    self.linear4 = torch.nn.Linear(2000,100)
    self.ident = nn.Identity()

def forward(self, x):
    a = self.linear1(x)
    a = self.relu1(a)
    a = self.linear2(a)
    a = self.relu1(a)
    a = self.linear3(a)
    a = torch.flatten(a)
    a = self.linear4(a)
    a = self.relu1(a)
    a = self.linear3(a)
    out = self.ident(a)
    return out
```

Loss is calculated as in the following order:

```
def get_policy(obs):
    logits = logits_net(obs)
    return Categorical(logits=logits.mean(0))
def get_action(obs):
    return get_policy(obs).sample().item()
def Logp(obs, act):
    logp = get_policy(obs).log_prob(act.cuda())
    return logp
def compute_loss(logp, weights):
    return -(logp * weights).mean()





 def train_one_epoch():
    # make some empty lists for logging.
    batch_obs = []          # for observations
    batch_acts = []         # for actions  
    batch_weights = []      # for R(tau) weighting in policy gradient
    batch_logp = []

    # reset episode-specific variables
    j = 1            # signal from environment that episode is over
    ep_rews = []            # list for rewards accrued throughout ep
   
    for i, data in enumerate(train_loader):
       
        #Create the mean image out of those 100 images
        x, label = data
        x = model(x.cuda())#torch.Size([100, 10])
        obs = x.data.cpu().numpy()#[100, 10] - a trajectory with only one state 
        # Save obs
        batch_obs.append(obs.copy())
      
        #act in the environment
        #act = get_action(torch.as_tensor(obs, dtype=torch.float32))
        act = get_action(x)
        print('action type', type(act))
        #log probability
        #logp = Logp(torch.as_tensor(obs, dtype=torch.float32),act = torch.as_tensor(act, dtype=torch.int32))
        logp = Logp(x, act = torch.as_tensor(act, dtype=torch.int32))
        #rew = reward(obs, act+2)
        rew = reward(x, act+2)
        
        # save action, reward
        batch_acts.append(act)
        batch_weights.append(rew)#episode rewards
        batch_logp.append(logp)
    
    opt.zero_grad()
    batch_logp = torch.stack(batch_logp, dim=0)
    batch_loss = compute_loss(logp = torch.as_tensor(batch_logp, dtype=torch.float32), 
                              weights = torch.as_tensor(batch_weights, dtype=torch.float32))

    
    batch_loss.backward() #does it return anything? gradients? print them!
    opt.step()

    for name, param in logits_net.named_parameters():
       print(name, param.grad)
```

I applied some changes with the assumption that maybe recreating some of the tensors maybe the issue:
I have the output of the first network, obs, converted like `obs = x.data.cpu().numpy()` this and then sent to get_action function: `act = get_action(torch.as_tensor(obs, dtype=torch.float32))`. I changes this to `act = get_action(x)` so, x is sent directly to this function. Also, change arguments of logp to  `logp = Logp(x, act = torch.as_tensor(act, dtype=torch.int32))`.
After these changes, I still get the none value for the gradient. Is there anyway possible to backpropagate the gradient when loss is calculated this way? any changes that I can apply?

any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is `return Categorical(logits=logits.mean(0))`? You cannot transform logits into categorical (via `argmax` or some `threshold`) and backpropagate through this node. You cannot cast tensors which require gradient to `numpy` either. `reward` function is also undefined.

Comment: logits is the output of second network and has a size [100,20]. I need it to be a vector of 20 values so logits = logits.mean(0). I tried changing this part by writing another architecture for the second network that returns a tensor with the size 20, but that also didn't solve the gradient issue. Could you elaborate on the second part (casting tensors to numpy?). I have done this once in my code but I am not using the output. I added the definition of reward function.

Comment: I meant `Categorical` object/function. Some pytorch functions are non-differentiable and you probably used one, hence you have `None` as gradients. Example could be `argmax`, which is usually used to transform one-hot encoding/logits/probabilties to indices with highest value. I suppose it's used in `Categorical`, isn't it?